# odd "warning C4127: conditional expression is constant" under VS2005

Tags: visual-studio-2005, compiler-warnings, c4127

I'm trying to compile [LightZPng](http://www.xmunkki.org/wiki/doku.php?id=projects:lightzpng) with warnings on level 4. I get a lot of C4127 on lines that are clearly not worthy of this warning. An example:

```
#define MAX_BITS 15
int values_per_bitlen[ MAX_BITS + 1 ];
for ( int i = 0; i <= MAX_BITS; ++i )    // C4127 is here
    values_per_bitlen[ i ] = 0;
```

How can this code be changed to avoid the warning other than #pragma?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a piece of code at the top of LightZ.cpp that goes like this:

```
#define for if (false) {} else for
```

That means your actual statement is:

```
#define for if (false) {} else for ( int i = 0; i <= MAX_BITS; ++i )
```

which is why you're getting the constant expression error (it's the `false`, not the `i <= MAX_BITS` as I thought).

Simply comment out or delete that line from the file (I can't actually figure out why they would do that).

Comment: Good catch, @WinProg, fleshed it out for you and +1'ed it.

Comment: Maybe this needs a further explanation? This causes every subsequent occurence of the token for to expand to an if statement containing a for statement. VC++ diagnoses if (false) as having a constant conditional expression, well no kidding. If you delete this line there will be fewer occurences of if (false) in the program.

Comment: We were typing at the same time. Sorry if my comment looks insulting.

Comment: No probs, I have pretty thick skin.

Comment: What, awesome catch. I didn't consider a #define since my syntax highlighting still marked it as a keyword (I guess that takes precedence in syntax highlighting).

Comment: The reason for the "#define for" is that older versions of Visual Studio had broken variable scoping in for loops: if you said for(int i = 0; ...), the variable "int i" would still be in alive after the loop was over.  The #define adds an extra level of scope, fixing the problem, so that code that does "for(int i = 0; ...) ...; for(i = 0; ...)" no longer compiles (as it rightly shouldn't).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/984878/what-is-the-possible-use-for-define-for-if-false-else-for for more info.

Comment: If I recall correctly, older versions of the C++ language defined the scope of the for variable exactly that way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that its odd. It's truly *not* a constant expression since `i` changes in the loop. So this would appear to be a problem with VS2005. For what it's worth, VS2008 does exactly the same thing.

Strangely enough, a project with *just* this in it does not complain so it may well be some weird edge-case problem with Microsoft's warning generation code:

```
#define MAX_BITS 15
int values_per_bitlen[ MAX_BITS + 1 ];
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    for ( int i = 0; i <= MAX_BITS; ++i )
        values_per_bitlen[ i ] = 0;
    return 0;
}
```

However, you haven't actually asked a question. What is it that you want to know, or want us to do?

**Update:**

See "Windows programmer"'s answer for the actual cause - there's a `"#define for if (false) {} else for"` at the top of LightZ.cpp which is causing the problem.

Comment: Added a question.. just basically want to change the code to avoid the warning without actually turning off the warning.

Comment: You want to change the code? Delete the line that I quoted in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it on my VS2005 and the warning does not appear, even at warning level 4. .

A simple procedure for you to follow :

-Create a new Console App and place only the above code and see if the warning shows up again.

-If not, check for differences in the project settings.

-If yes, I would assume that your optimization setting may be causing it.

Comment: Yeah sure, some project settings tell VC++ to check for stuff like if (false), and some project settings tell VC++ not the check for stuff like if (false).

Answer (score 0):

[According to Charles Nicholson](http://cnicholson.net/2009/03/stupid-c-tricks-dowhile0-and-c4127/), Visual Studio 2005 gives this error with the "`do...while(0)`" trick:

```
#define MULTI_LINE_MACRO \
    do { \
        doSomething(); \
        doSomethingElse(); \
    } while(0)
```

If you absolutely must, you can use the [__pragma](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9x1s805.aspx) directive to selectively disable that warning around a particular code fragment.

Comment: It also gives that warning for if (false), as we've seen in this question.