# scope of variable outside for loop

Tags: visual-c++

I'm trying to use a program written a few years ago and compiled in a previous version of MS VC++ (I am using VC++ 2008).  There are a lot (hundreds) of instances similar to the following:

```
int main () {
  int number = 0;
  int number2 = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
   //something using i
  }

  for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
   //something using i
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure which version it was originally compiled in, but it worked.  My question is: how did it work?  My understanding is that the i variable should only be defined for use in the first loop.  When I try to compile it now I get the error "'i': undeclared identifier" for the line starting the second loop, which makes sense.  Was this just overlooked in previous versions of VC++?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An earlier version of MSVC had this "misfeature" in that it leaked those variables into the enclosing scope.

In other words, it treated:

```
for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
    // something using i
}
```

the same as:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i<10; i++) {
    // something using i
}
```

See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984878/what-is-the-possible-use-for-define-for-if-false-else-for) I asked about a strange macro definition, for more detail.

Comment: Ok thanks.  That makes sense.  Not really looking forward to changing all those errors...

Comment: Maybe a global search and replace for `for (i =` with `for (int i =` ? Though that may give you errors going the _other_ way.

Comment: Your previously asked question was very insightful, thanks for the link! Maybe you're right, doing that search and replace will probably be less work, even if I have to go back and fix some other resultant errors.