# Redefine(#define) reserved c++ key word

Tags: c++

Is it possible to redefine a c++ keyword using #define?

```
#ifdef int
#undef int 
#define int 2
#endif
int main(){
    //Do something with int
}
```

I can't see the output in this case but i want to understand what happens internally. The reason I don't have #define is that I found that it is possible to #define a reserved keyword if you don't use a standard header file. I also tried to do run the following code.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#ifdef int
#undef int 
#endif
int main(){
    cout<<int;
}
```

But te above throws the error at cout line.

Comment: What would `cout<<int` do? Why would you redefine `int`?

Comment: This question is similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726204/c-preprocessor-define-ing-a-keyword-is-it-standards-conforming

Comment: @mfontanini I was just trying to be more familiar with the #define and c++ in general. I don't have a usecase for that..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ preprocessor #define-ing a keyword. Is it standards conforming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726204/c-preprocessor-define-ing-a-keyword-is-it-standards-conforming)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible?  Yes.  Is it good style?  Absolutely not.

The preprocessor is not aware of C/C++ keywords, it only knows about preprocessor tokens and just does strict text replacement.

Your example is resulting in an error because you're `#undef`ing it.  Once you undefine it, it reverts to its previous behavior.

The only valid use I know of for doing something like this is to [work around a bug in an old compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984878/what-is-the-possible-use-for-define-for-if-false-else-for), and that compiler is no longer relevant these days.

Answer (score 1):

Technically it works but it probably won't do you much good. If you want to use the standard C++ library you are not allowed define any of the keywords or any of a set of other names according to 17.6.4.3.1 [macro.names] paragraph 2:

> A translation unit shall not #define or #undef names lexically identical to keywords, to the identifiers listed in Table 3, or to the attribute-tokens described in 7.6.

Answer (score 0):

You *can*, but you shouldn't.

In your examples, `int` doesn't get redefined, since it's wrapped in `#ifdef int`. That means "only do this if there's already a preprocessor macro called `int`", and there isn't.

If you just wrote `#define int 2`, then all occurrences of `int` would be replaced by `2`; but then your code wouldn't compile since `2 main() {cout<<2;}` is nonsense.

`#undef` will not remove a keyword from the language; it only removes preprocessor macros previously defined using `#define`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're don't use the standard libraries you're allowed to do so. In fact the preprocessor shouldn't distinguish between reserved and non-reserved words.

However that's probably not why you run into problems. First of all your examples don't do what you probably think. The fault is that `int` is normally not a preprocessor defined macro. The `#ifdef int` directive will therefore skip the following lines up to the terminating `#endif`.

What this means is that your second example expands to:

```
// stuff from iostream and possibly other headers 

int main(){
    cout<<int;
}
```

the fault is that `cout<<int;` simply isn't allowed.