# C MACRO to trace the "for" loop iteration in the existing source code

Tags: c++, c, macros

I require a c/c++ MACRO to trace the "for" loop iterations in the existing source code and to print some message if loop is running more that 50 iterations.
NOTE: the macro should not change the existing functionality of code.
I tried some logic [C/C++: "for" macro to track loops which are running many iterations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30659340/c-c-for-macro-to-track-loops-which-are-running-many-iterations) but it is not working in all cases!

```
  int main()
  {
    int i,j,x,y;
    j=100;
    y=200;

    //case 1
    for(i=0;i<j;i++)   
        for(x=0;x<y;x) 
        x++;


    //case 2
    if(i>0)
      for(;i>0;)    
        i--;

     //case 3
     for(;;)  
     {
        i++;
     }

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please, there is nothing `c/c++`, don't promote it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C/C++: "for" macro to track loops which are running many iterations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30659340/c-c-for-macro-to-track-loops-which-are-running-many-iterations)

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30659340/c-c-for-macro-to-track-loops-which-are-running-many-iterations) it is failing in above mentioned cases

Comment: @RakshithKumarN You said that it "failed", but didn't say how.

Comment: @Carcigenicate That implementation is assuming the for loop will have all (or at least the last) sections. If called with `for(;;)`, it will end up with `for(;; , something)`, which is a compile error.

Comment: @Carcigenicate In case 2 we are declaring FORlOOPCOUNTM in "if" block and trying to use it in "for" loop block so we will get variable not declared in the scope error!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof of concept that passes all three cases:

```
// Max lines in a file you are profiling
#define MAX_LINES 65535
// Array to count all iterations, initialized to zero
uint32_t iterations[MAX_LINES];
// Increments the iteration for the given line, returns non-zero
#define ITER(ln)  ++iterations[ln]
// Override for definition
#define for(...) for(__VA_ARGS__) if (!ITER(__LINE__)) { } else
```

The limitation here is that you can only have one `for` per line, otherwise it will combine their iterations. So, this is okay:

```
for(i=0;i<j;i++)   
    for(x=0;x<y;x)
        x++;
```

but this isn't:

```
for(i=0;i<j;i++) for(x=0;x<y;x) x++;
```

The other limitation is that we define an array for every line. You can easily make it a hashmap or something, but that isn't relevant for this example. With a hashmap, you can use the `__LINE__` and `#x` (string representation of the loop) to construct the ID, so the first limitation mostly goes away as well.

Comment: on c++ i changed to "#define ITER(ln)  iterations[ln]++" to make it work

Comment: @UzumakiIchigo I don't do much C++, but I'm completely baffled that it doesn't implement the comma operator properly. Anyway, I've updated the code to make it work in both - you need `++iterations[ln]` and `if (!ITER(__LINE__))` instead, since it will return different values.