# _Pragma and macro substitution

Tags: c, macros, undefined-behavior

In implementing my own C11 compiler, I'm trying to figure out how exactly to handle the `_Pragma` keyword/operator. C11 §6.10.9 describes `_Pragma` as being an operator, so it seems possible to redefine it with macros, i.e. `#define _Pragma(x) SOME_OTHER_MACRO(x)`. Further, the statement `#undef _Pragma` should have no effect (assuming no prior `#define` of `_Pragma`). This is similar to how keywords can be `#define`d, such as the old VC++ hack `#define for if (0) ; else for`. However, because the `_Pragma` operator is evaluated during translation phase 3, the same phase as executing preprocessor directives, it's not clear whether this is an exception; the standard doesn't mention whether its undefined behavior to use `_Pragma` as a macro name.

I did some testing with GCC using the following code:

```
#define PRAGMA _Pragma
PRAGMA("message \"hi\"")

_Pragma ("message \"sup\"")

#undef PRAGMA

#undef _Pragma
//#define _Pragma(x)
_Pragma("message \"hello\"")
```

Compiling with `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -c` outputs:

```
tmp.c:2:1: note: #pragma message: hi
 PRAGMA("message \"hi\"")
 ^
tmp.c:4:1: note: #pragma message: sup
 _Pragma ("message \"sup\"")
 ^
tmp.c:8:8: warning: undefining "_Pragma" [enabled by default]
 #undef _Pragma
        ^
tmp.c:10:9: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before string constant
 _Pragma("message \"hello\"")
         ^
```

If I add the line `#undef _Alignof`, GCC doesn't complain about it.

This suggests that GCC implements `_Pragma` through a macro (via the warning message), and that undefining it results in a compile error. If I uncomment `#define _Pragma(x)`, the error goes away (as the string literal disappears).

So, my questions are:

1. Are implementations allowed to define `_Pragma` as just a macro, and not implement it as an operator?
2. If not, is GCC wrong in doing so?
3. if `_Pragma` is supposed to be an operator, is it undefined behavior to define `_Pragma` as a macro?
4. Is there any ordering between `_Pragma` evaluation and other preprocessor directives? Or do they have the same "precedence" (i.e. they're evaluated in-order)?

Again, looking through the C11 standard does not mention anything about `_Pragma` other than it's an operator that can be used for `#pragma` directives.

Comment: Anticipate some substantial level of opinion will play a roll in the answers you get to this question, ( like the `void main(void)` discussions ) however, your research is evident, and your questions are well presented.  Should result in interesting responses. (+1)

Comment: I'm not sure, if I understand the standard correctly here, but I think, C11 7.1.3 p3 applies: “If the program removes (with #undef) any macro definition of an identifier in the first group listed above, the behavior is undefined.” where the mentioned “first group” are identifiers beginning with an underscore followed by another underscore or an uppercase letter.

Comment: @mafso that seems to only apply if there's a macro definition in the first place, so code like `#ifndef _Pragma <newline>#undef _Pragma<newline>#endif` would not invoke UB

Comment: @DrewMcGowen - If the C11 standard defines _Pragma as _A unary operator expression of the form:_
 ***_Pragma (*** string-literal ***)***..., And an implementation chooses to implement it in a different way, would that other implementation be considered C?  (reference 6.10.9 Pragma operator, in C11 standard, Committee Draft — April 12, 2011)

Comment: "similar to how keywords can be #defined, such as the old VC++ hack #define for if (0) ; else for" — …wow. I never heard of this before — https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984878/what-is-the-possible-use-for-define-for-if-false-else-for

Answer (score 7):

There is no need for a special rule that would forbid `_Pragma` to be a macro name. Having a leading underscore and capital letter, it is among the reserved identifiers that you are not supposed to use, anyhow. Using reserved identifiers leads to undefined behavior of your program, a compiler may do anything.

An implementation may implement it as a macro, but that should be transparent to you, as long as you use it correctly, that is as long as you don't mess around with it. The only important thing that an implementation must guarantee is that the "destringization" and "tokeninzation" of the argument to the `_Pragma` is done as if in phase 3 (which is difficult if it is "only" a macro) and that the resulting `#pragma` directive is processed in phase 4.

Comment: It's almost unclear what the standard means by "reserved for any use" - surely, a statement such as `int ln = __LINE__;` could be considered a use of the identifier `__LINE__` (unless "reserved for any use" does not include mandatory identifiers).

Comment: @DrewMcGowen: "reserved for any use" means that the user cannot declare or define identifiers of that form for any use (since it's reserved).  Contrast that with identifier forms that are reserved only for identifiers with file scope or only if a specific header is included.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen, this has a very precise meaning which is provided in 7.1.3. Paragraph 2 says what you are not supposed to do with it: *If the program declares or defines an identifier in a
context in which it is reserved (other than as allowed by 7.1.4), or defines a reserved
identifier as a macro name, the behavior is undefined.*

Comment: _Having a leading underscore and capital letter, it is among the reserved identifiers that you are not supposed to use,..._  +1

Comment: Is `_Pragma` a "full citizen" as a C operator? I mean, would `int *c = _Pragma(ObscureIntAllocator);` be legal C code?